# I couldn't Press Two Buttons on Matrix Keypad with Arduino

Tags: button, arduino, project, lcd, keypad

My english is not perfect, so I am sorry. I hope you understand my problem.
I am working on an arduino project. I connected a 4x3 Matrix Keypad to Arduino. Now, when I press '1' on keypad, A is showing on LCD Display and when I press '2', B is showing on LCD. **But I want when I press two buttons on keypad (both of 1 and 2) C is shown on the screen.** But I couldn't. I trying to receive data from two buttons at the same time but I couldn't. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use the [Keypad library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Keypad).

This library has a function called `getKeys()` which populates a list with all the pressed keys.

Then you can call `isPressed(keyChar)` on each of the keys you want to make sure both are pressed.

Be careful not to arrange a sequence of if/else statements so that a single key press satisfies an earlier if condition so that a double key press in some later condition is never checked.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this, and I will write the results here

Comment: Hello @UncleO; I work try your proposal, but I couldn't. I think you aren't understand my question or I couldn't explain. I will use 6 buttons on keypad. Every button has a character. But some characters will show with pressing two buttons. For example I only press 1 button, A is shown on the screen. But when I press 1 and 2 button, C is shown on the screen. I want if I don't press any button after I press 1 button, A is shown on the screen. But if I press 2 button after press 1 button, C is shown on the screen. That is possible ? If it is true, how can I do?

Comment: And, I don't know how to use getKeys() and isPressed(keyChar)